# Vue + Nuxt.js - How to cache a whole page with components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, caching, nuxt.js

I have a Vue + nuxt.js app which renders a couple of pages with Highcharts. The charts are created by a dynamic component that takes as a parameter a web service URL. How can I cache such pages for approximately 1 day?

I have found the two links, but these only refer to component caching, not the whole page. The component cache would cache the component based on a 'name' and would hinder to cache dynamically which takes a parameter? Therefore this approach doesn't look right for me.

- [nuxt cached components](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/cached-components/)
- [vue ssr component level caching](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/caching.html#component-level-caching)

Any suggestions on how I can cache my pages?

An example page where I call the dynamic component with the URL parameter:

```
<template>
   <keep-alive>
    <chart :url="this.$axios.defaults.baseURL + 'api/analytics/age'" keep-alive/>
  </keep-alive>
</template>

<script>
    import chart from '~/components/analytics/chart'

    export default {
        components: {
          chart,
        },      
    }
</script>
```

An example of the dynamic component, this takes the parameter and then does a web service call to get the data for rendering the chart.

```
<template>
  <highcharts v-if="isChartDataLoaded" :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'
    import Highcharts3D from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d'
    import Highcharts from 'highcharts'

    if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
        Highcharts3D(Highcharts);
    }

    export default {
        name: 'chart',
        props: ['url'],
        serverCacheKey: props => props.url,
        components: {
            highcharts: Chart
        },
        data() {
            return {
                isChartDataLoaded: false,
                chartOptions: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.2f}%',
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 50,
                        },
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: '',
                        data: [1],
                        tooltip: {
                            valueDecimals: 0
                        },
                        animation: false

                    }],
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            innerSize: '30%',
                            depth: 100,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                percentageDecimals: 2,
                                color: '#002a52',
                                connectorColor: '#002a52',
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + ' %';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            printButton: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            contextButton: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.post(this.url, {
                locale: this.$route.query.locale ? this.$route.query.locale : this.$i18n.locale
            }).then(response => {
                this.chartOptions.series[0].data = response.data;
                this.isChartDataLoaded = true
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

My response is late but I hope it helps other people searching for an answer. If you want to cache a whole page, you can use [nuxt-ssr-cacge](https://github.com/arash16/nuxt-ssr-cache). 
Then in your nuxt.config.js :

```js
module.exports = {
  // If you provide a version, it will be stored inside cache.
  // Later when you deploy a new version, old cache will be
  // automatically purged.
  version: pkg.version,

  // ....

  modules: [
      'nuxt-ssr-cache',
  ],
  cache: {
    // if you're serving multiple host names (with differing
    // results) from the same server, set this option to true.
    // (cache keys will be prefixed by your host name)
    // if your server is behind a reverse-proxy, please use
    // express or whatever else that uses 'X-Forwarded-Host'
    // header field to provide req.hostname (actual host name)
    useHostPrefix: false,
    pages: [
      // these are prefixes of pages that need to be cached
      // if you want to cache all pages, just include '/'
      '/page1',
      '/page2',

      // you can also pass a regular expression to test a path
      /^\/page3\/\d+$/,

      // to cache only root route, use a regular expression
      /^\/$/
    ],
    
    key(route, context) {
      // custom function to return cache key, when used previous
      // properties (useHostPrefix, pages) are ignored. return 
      // falsy value to bypass the cache
    },

    store: {
      type: 'memory',

      // maximum number of pages to store in memory
      // if limit is reached, least recently used page
      // is removed.
      max: 100,

      // number of seconds to store this page in cache
      ttl: 86400, //Actually One day
    },
  },

  // ...
};
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

here is new solution for cache the whole page

even you can cache consistent api like menu if you need

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-perfect-cache

`npm i nuxt-perfect-cache`

```
// nuxt.config.js

modules: [
    [
        'nuxt-perfect-cache',
        {
          disable: false,
          appendHost: true,
          ignoreConnectionErrors:false, //it's better to be true in production
          prefix: 'r-',
          url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
          getCacheData(route, context) {          
            if (route !== '/') {
              return false
            }
            return { key: 'my-home-page', expire: 60 * 60 }//1hour
          }
        }
      ]
]
```